# Adding numbers in a list with numbers of another list

Tags: python, list

How can i use a for loop to obtain output 1 and output 2 without hard coding the index ?Or is there any better method to do this without using a loop ?

```
x=[1.0,2.0]

y=[[1.0,2.0],[3.0,4.0]]

z=[2.0,3.0]

output1 : (x[0]*y[0][0]+x[1]*y[0][1]) *z[0]

output2 : (x[0]*y[1][0]+ x[1]*y[1][1]) *z[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1.0, 2.0]
y = [[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
z = [2.0, 3.0]

for b, c in zip(y, z):
    print(sum(a * v for a, v in zip(x, b)) * c)
```

Prints:

```
10.0
33.0
```

---

Or: If you have only two input variables:

```
output1, output2 = [sum(a * v for a, v in zip(x, b)) * c for b, c in zip(y, z)]
print(output1)
print(output2)
```

Prints:

```
10.0
33.0
```